# How to mock FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

How can I mock FirebaseInstanceId?
All I want to do is when I call the method

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

It should return me an empty string.

I have tried using PowerMockRunner as well.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnit4.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FirebaseInstanceId.class})
public class NotificationServiceTest {
```

When I do the following:

```
FirebaseInstanceId firebaseInstanceId = mock(FirebaseInstanceId.class);
    Mockito.when(firebaseInstanceId.getInstance()).thenReturn(firebaseInstanceId);
```

I get the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method myPid in android.os.Process not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

Comment: Maybe this can be solver by returning default values from Android methods?
`testOptions { unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true }` in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(RuntimeEnvironment.application)`

In your test case if you are using Robolectric or otherwise pass in relevant `Application`